# setting up google analytics for an all-ajax site

Tags: google-analytics

i call trackpageview within the onstatechange callback (which i checked is being called), because in an all-ajax site, the states are the pages.

```
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {
_gaq.push([ '_trackPageview', History.getState().url ]); 
}
```

i also have the necessary snippet in the  (again, which is only ever called once, because this site is all-ajax).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-31081343-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() { ... })();

</script>
```

however, i do not see these pageviews on my google analytics account, neither in 'standard reporting' nor in the 'realtime'.

why aren't these pageviews being tracked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume you use [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/))

History.getState().url return the complete URL, begining with the protocol (http://...).

When using `pageURL` parameter with `_trackPageview`, you **must** use a beginning slash (/) to indicate the page URL (cf [doc](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview)). Otherwise the request will not be taken into account by Google Analytics.

Comment: yeah i thought of that walking to class. but you still get accepted :)

Comment: Thx ;-) Note that some bugs like https://github.com/balupton/history.js/issues/72 in History.js can compromise your statistics...

Comment: yikes. i had thought we'd be safe supporting only chrome & firefox (young demographic). thanks dude.